How to use Mongo Realm with Next Js (App router) SSR?
I'm trying to set up user registration and login in a Next.js application using the App Router with MongoDB Realm. I have set up an API handler for login, and it works fine as the response is returned and the cookie is set correctly. However, after logging in, app.currentUser returns null when I try to get user details with a getUser API. Here are my API handlers:
Login API:
import { createSessionToken } from "@/app/lib/authUtils";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { App, Credentials } from "realm-web";

const app = new App({ id: "app-id" });

export async function POST(req: Request) {
  try {
    const { email, password } = await req.json();

    if (!email || !password) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { error: "Email and password are required" },
        { status: 400 }
      );
    }

    const credentials = Credentials.emailPassword(email, password);
    const user = await app.logIn(credentials);

    if (!user) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { error: "Invalid email or password" },
        { status: 401 }
      );
    }

    const token = createSessionToken({
      email: user.profile.email ?? "",
      name: user.profile.name ?? "",
      token: user.accessToken ?? "",
    });

    const res = NextResponse.json({ user });
    res.cookies.set("session", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      maxAge: 60 * 30, // 30 minutes
      path: "/",
    });

    return res;
  } catch (error: any) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
}



Get User API:
import { getSession } from "@/app/lib/authUtils";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { App } from "realm-web";

const app = new App({ id: "app-id" });

export async function GET(req: Request) {
  try {
    const sessionData = await getSession(); 
    if (!sessionData || !sessionData.token) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { error: "No session token found" },
        { status: 401 }
      );
    }

    const user = app.currentUser;
    const checkSameUser = user?.accessToken === sessionData.token && user;

    return NextResponse.json({ data: checkSameUser }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error: any) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
}




I expect the getUser API to return the details of the logged-in user, but it gives null.
My Questions:

Why is app.currentUser returning null after a successful login?

Is it possible to achieve this functionality with my current stack?

How can I correctly get the logged-in user's details after login?


Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

You should understand the lifecycle and scope of Realm.App instance and how user sessions are managed in a serverless environment.

Realm.App instance's user state is not maintained across different requests. In a typical serverless function, That kind of instance is created anew for each request, meaning that even if a user logs in and a session token is generated, subsequent API requests will create a new Realm.App instance that does not have the previous user's session.

It's possible to achieve this functionality using your current stack. You can make sure that the session token generated upon login is validated and used to authenticate the user in subsequent requests.

To correctly get the logged-in user's details after login,

Store the session token in a secure cookie after login, and retrieve, validate the session token in subsequent requests.
Re-authenticate the user using the session token.



GetUser API
import { getSession } from "@/app/lib/authUtils";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { App, Credentials } from "realm-web";

const app = new App({ id: "app-id" });

export async function GET(req: Request) {
  try {
    const sessionToken = req.headers.get("cookie")?.match(/session=([^;]+)/)?.[1];

    if (!sessionToken) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { error: "No session token found" },
        { status: 401 }
      );
    }

    // Validate the session token and extract user details (implement your own validation)
    const sessionData = getSession(sessionToken);

    if (!sessionData || !sessionData.token) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { error: "Invalid session token" },
        { status: 401 }
      );
    }

    // Re-authenticate the user with the session token
    const credentials = Credentials.jwt(sessionData.token);
    const user = await app.logIn(credentials);

    if (!user) {
      return NextResponse.json(
        { error: "User re-authentication failed" },
        { status: 401 }
      );
    }

    return NextResponse.json({ data: user }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error: any) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
}

Example of getSession
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const SECRET_KEY = process.env.SECRET_KEY;

export function getSession(token) {
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, SECRET_KEY);
    return decoded;
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
}


Just a question about your point #1: subsequent API requests will create a new Realm.App instance that does not have the previous user's session. If this code is called let app = new Realm.App(config); anywhere after authentication, app.current user contains the current user. Does it contain the previous users session and the user? Doesn't Realm authentication implement session management to preserve authentication state across different parts of the app? Just curious
